# Cannot format micro sd card

Tags: gparted, format, sd-card

I apparently did something wrong while trying to format my micro sd card 8 GB. I have used it for one and a half year in my old phone without any problems and now I wanted to format it to use in my new Jolla phone. My old phone says it's damaged, Ubuntu doesn't mount the card, neither does Windows 7 btw. Neither can format it.

Here's the result of the last try:
I opened gParted and let it look for the card. It detected and mounted it, but it takes an awfully long time finding the partitions on the card. I closed gParted and tried to see if I could write to the card. That seemed to be possible, but at the next time mounting the file was gone. I tried to unmount the card through Nautilus but I got the message that files were being written to the device and I have to wait. Light on the USB reader kept blinking fast. After some time I got the following error: Error ejecting /dev/sdb: Command-line `eject "/dev/sdb"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: eject: unable to open`/dev/sdb'.

I pulled out the card and plugged it in again. Now the computer recognizes it immediately, but as I pointed out before, the document was gone. This time gParted recognizes the device as a device with one Fat32 partition. I unmounted the card, which took again very long. I tried to format it as ext4, which gave me en error in the last phase, saying: errors while writing superblocs (translated from Dutch, not sure if this the exact same error in English).

Does anyone know what went wrong? I did manage to change the file system, apparently, but it still doesn't work the way it's supposed to. Or is this sd card just ruined?

Comment: When I closed gParted after this, it said that the device /dev/sdb does not exist.

Comment: Instead of formatting the card with gparted, try writing a new partition table, then create a partition and format it.